# Populating an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble populating a 2 dimensional array in java.

```
private int[][] array = new int[1][1];
array[|0][0] = 1;
```

error ']' expected at the |

Comment: Did you try removing the `|`?

Comment: @casablanca is right I think. Side comment (Moved): When your compiler throws an error often the terminal compiler error printed will give information that can help. Getting familiar with reading these can help understand the causes of certain types of errors. It is worth learning about this for when you have problems.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that this code is (probably) outside of any method.  In Java, statements have to be inside a method or initializer.  Try defining a `main` method and then putting the code `array[0][0] = 1` inside of it and see if that solves things.  For example:

```
public class YourClass {
    private int[][] array = new int[1][1];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        array[0][0] = 1;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: THANK YOU
I knew i was missing something so simple.